# Map marker and list in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

My requirement is when i click on certain markers on google map, the places must be updated in a list in bootstrap. But when i click the array is updated but the list is not updated in bootstrap. When i used infowindow everything worked.

html

```
<div class="panel-body">
     <ul style="padding-left:0px;">
         <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info" ng-repeat="x in routesub" style="font-size:smaller;">
             <span class="badge" ng-click="delloc(x)">x</span>
                {{x}}
         </li>
     </ul>
     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="subsearch()">SUBSCRIBE</button>
</div>
```

app.js

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
  return function () {

                   // var content1 = "<div><h6><font color='black'>" + locations[i].Name + "</font></h6><input type = 'button' class = 'btn btn-success btn-sm' value = 'Select' ng-click = 'SubLoc();' /></div>";
                    //var content = $compile(content1)($scope);
                    //$scope.infowindow.setContent(content[0]);
                    //$scope.infowindow.open($scope.map, marker);
                    $scope.SubLoc = function () {
                        if ($scope.routesub.indexOf(locations[i].Name) == -1) {
                            $scope.routesub.push(locations[i].Name);
                            $scope.routeidsub1.push(locations[i].LocationId);
                            marker.setIcon(icon_sel);
                           // $scope.infowindow.close();
                        }
                        else {
                            //$scope.infowindow.close();
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.SubLoc();

                }
            })(marker, i));
```

When I uncommented those commented parts and used infowindow everything worked out perfecftly. After commenting when I click on marker the data is stored in `$scope.routesub` but not visible in html.Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are out of the "angular world" in your google event listener you have angular to tell that it has to start a digest cycle to refresh its bound values.

Wrap the values you want to update into an [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) function like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.routesub.push(locations[i].Name);
});
```

Alternatively you can also use [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) (my preferred way) because it produces no "digest already running" errors:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.routesub.push(locations[i].Name);
});
```